# How to tell if a JMS Session is async

Tags: java, jms

I need to write some code that only calls `acknowledge` if the session is synchronous because otherwise `acknowledge` throws a `JMSCC0033` for not being able to call it against an async session (same as [JMS Acknowledge Asynchronous Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669746/jms-acknowledge-asynchronous-message)) . However I cannot find a method or means to check the session itself. There is an internal implementation of `isAsync`, but nothing I can see externally. Would checking if there is a listener be enough? Am I totally missing something in the documentation?

This is library code, where the mode can be set via config, however I am fairly sure that it is ClientAcknowledge based on the user reports. This is a library that wants to clear all messages while closing, however runs into this exception periodically. From my decompiling the code I have come to the conclusion that it seems that there is no exposed way to check...which seems like a flaw since it can blow things up and has an internal mechanism to check it that seems easily exposable. Right now I am thinking I will have to just catch and swallow the exception...

Comment: What acknowledgement mode is the session using? Please provide relevant code and a more thorough description of your use-case.

Comment: This is library code, where the mode can be set via config, however I am fairly sure that it is `ClientAcknowledge` based on the user report. This is a library that wants to clear all messages while closing, however runs into this exception periodically. From my decompiling the code I have come to the conclusion that it seems that there is no exposed way to check...which seems like a flaw since it can blow things up and has an internal mechanism to check it that seems easily exposable. Right now I am thinking I will have to just catch and swallow the exception...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a session to create a `Producer` to *send* messages asynchronously or you can use a session to create a `Consumer` and register a `MessageListener` to *receive* messages asynchronously. However, there is no overall concept in JMS of a "sync" or "async" session.

To be clear, it's perfectly acceptable to invoke `acknowledge()` on the `Message` received by the `onMessage()` method of a `MessageListener`. Here's some sample code that works perfectly well with ActiveMQ Artemis:

```java
ConnectionFactory cf = ...
Connection c = cf.createConnection();
Session s = c.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination q = s.createQueue("myQueue");
MessageConsumer mc = s.createConsumer(q);
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
c.start();
mc.setMessageListener(message -> {
   try {
      message.acknowledge();
      System.out.println("Message acknowledged!");
      latch.countDown();
   } catch (JMSException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
});
MessageProducer mp = s.createProducer(q);
mp.send(s.createMessage());
latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It will print:

```
Message acknowledged!
```

It's also worth keeping in mind that a JMS `Session` is not thread-safe so if you're accessing the same session from multiple threads concurrently then you're going to have problems.

Comment: I added a little more reasoning - that it otherwise throws an exception. So, how am I supposed to proactively check against this. It is a library method, so setup of the session is not in the scope and I need a way to avoid this exception.

Comment: @JustinPihony Read the answer. It's not about the 'setup of the session'. It is how the `Producer` or `Consumer` was created.